# C code error: expected ';' before '{' token

Tags: c, while-loop

When I run the code, I get this error :

```
In function 'print':
error:  expected ';' before '{' token
```

I'm using `gcc` compiler, I can't really find what I'm missing here:

***Code***:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void print(char *C)
{
  int i = 0;
  While(C[i] != '\0')
  { 
     printf("%c",C[i]);
     i++;
  }
  printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
  char C[20] = "Hello";
  print(C);
}
```

Comment: Next time, use `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` to compile, and use a more recent GCC - e.g. version 4.9 or 5 (it might have suggested the correction).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
While(C[i] != '\0')
```

should be

```
while(C[i] != '\0')   /* Note the lower-case 'w' */
```

Remember that the C programming language is case sensitive.

Comment: The error message arises because it assumes that `While` is the name of a function you're calling, and so there should be a `;` at the end .

Comment: Hi Matt, it's not about ; at the end, It has been answered by Cool Guy

Comment: Sorry about it Matt.